# How to delete specific string from filename in bash

Tags: bash, sed, tr

I have a file named "Some Text - Full Score_0.png" and I need to delete that " - Full Score" part from it and replace all remaining spaces in "Some Text" by "-".

I'm able to remove all spaces using `tr ' ' '-'`

I need output to be "some-text_0.png"...

Does anyone have an idea, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for it!

```
"$file" | cut -d- -f1 | sed 's/.$//' | tr ' ' '-'
```

If you find out some other, better solution, please let me know.

Comment: `"$file" |` is meant to be `cat "$file" |` or maybe `echo "$file" |`?

Comment: Yes, it's echo "$file"... But I meant solution for those piped commands.. If it's easier, or more efective way to do that..

Answer (score 1):

You can use Parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash
in='Some Text - Full Score_0.png'
expected='some-text_0.png'

out=${in/ - Full Score}  # Replace
out=${out// /-}          # Replace everywhere
out=${out,,}             # Lowercase all

[[ $expected == $out ]] && echo ok
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a neat command line utility called [rename](https://metacpan.org/pod/rename). It comes by default in Ubuntu, but is also available for Mac.

It works like `sed(1)`, but on file names:

```
$ touch 'Some Text - Full Score_0.png'
$ ls
Some Text - Full Score_0.png
$ rename -e 's/ - Full Score//; s/ /-/g; y/A-Z/a-z/' Some\ Text\ -\ Full\ Score_0.png 
$ ls
some-text_0.png
```

`s/ - Full Score//` removes the text in question.

`s/ /-/g` replaces spaces with hyphens.

`y/A-Z/a-z/` lowercases all letters.